# Duvidas de SQL Não sei como organizar esta query

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo umas vídeo aulas de mysql e apareceu uma tarefa e não consigo chegar na logica para resolver esta query.

`Quantos produtos foram comprados por pelo menos 1.000 clientes únicos`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo contar quantos produtos foram comprados por todos os cliente e por cliente

`SELECT SUM(product_id) as quantidade from orders;`

`SELECT customer_id, SUM(product_id) as quantidade from orders group by customer_id;`

como que faria para devolver a quantidade produtos que foram comprados por pelo menos 1000 clientes ?

Proposição de uma solução

```
select count(distinct(x.product_id))
from
(
    select product_id
    from orders
    group by product_id having(count(customer_id)>=1000)
    
) as x
inner join orders as y on x.product_id = y.product_id
group by x.product_id
```

Answer (score -1):

achei uma possível solução pesquisando na doc do MYSQL é a utilização de `EXISTS`

o resultado foi :

```
select count(distinct(x.product_id))
from
(
    select product_id
    from orders
    group by product_id having(count(customer_id)>=2)
    
) as x
inner join orders as y on x.product_id = y.product_id
group by x.product_id
```

se alguem quiser compartilhar uma forma mais performática de fazer isso seria um grande aprendizado. Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

```
Select count(product_id) qtd
From
(Select product_id
 From orders
 Group by product_id
 Having count(distinct costumer_id) >= 1000)) T1
```

Creio ser isto , sem testar todavia. O *distinct* pois o cliente pode ter comprado um produto mais de uma vez.

Comment: nao funciona. ele da erros na query tentei arrumar mas mesmo assim nao foi ;(

Comment: veja o que vc acha da alteração que eu fiz vou editar meu post

Comment: O erro foi aqui !?